# How would one begin to write code to generate Lichtenberg figures (lightning fractal tree)?

Tags: python, graphics, drawing, draw, fractals

How would one begin to write an algorithm to generate Lichtenberg figures (which is a fractal tree created from an electric discharge like lightning)?

This Lichtenberg figure is a special type of fractal tree different from the standard textbook example (e.g., http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Fractal_tree), which generally are symmetric, ordered, non-stochastic, etc.  Lichtenberg figures would need to be stochastically generated, non-symmetric, with variable branch widths (thicknesses).  Branching also involves very small branches and twigs directly from very large trunks.  If there is a bifurcation, generally one branch may be smaller than the other branch.

[image: Lichtenberg figure radial]
<sub>(source: [capturedlightning.com](http://capturedlightning.com/photos/For_Sale/June04/3InchDisk/CenterLED1b.jpg))</sub>

[image: Lichtenberg figure]

https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/77974/how-is-a-lichtenberg-figure-created

Answer (score 2):

The things that come reasonably close (although you'd probably have to do a fair bit of tweaking until you get something looking 'right') are Diffusion-limited Aggregation trees.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffusion-limited_aggregation

That seems to have some fairly recent references, including implementations. As you can imagine, generating these is not exactly fast.